# Visual studio 2005 autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2005

I have visual studio express 2010.
Each time I write `#include "file.h"`  it autocompletes it for me when I befin typing.

I have another version with visual studio 2005 which isn't express.
In it I don't have this autocomplete.

Do you know why would this difference be?
Is there any configuration I must do on visual studio 2005 to have this autocomplete or is it just not available in 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-complete on #include directives is a feature that's exclusive to VS2010 and up.  It has a completely redesigned IntelliSense parser, you cannot get this feature in VS2005.  Microsoft doesn't back-port new features to old versions.